# Microsoft SMA Could not find a parameter named ‘0’

Tags: powershell

This is an old setup on SMA which was working all this while. Of late last weekend we are getting this error while running any runbook on SMA.

We are getting error

> At line:12 char:25 + $allComputers = Get-AutomationVariable “TestExecutor_Computers” + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Could not find a parameter named ‘0’. Supported parameters are: Debug, DisplayName, ErrorAction, Input, MergeErrorToOutput, Name, PSActionRetryCount, PSActionRetryIntervalSec, PSActionRunningTimeoutSec, PSAllowRedirection, PSApplicationName, PSAuthentication, PSCertificateThumbprint, PSComputerName, PSConfigurationName, PSConnectionRetryCount, PSConnectionRetryIntervalSec, PSConnectionUri, PSCredential, PSDebug, PSDisableSerialization, PSError, PSPersist, PSPort, PSProgress, PSProgressMessage, PSRemotingBehavior, PSRequiredModules, PSSessionOption, PSUseSsl, PSVerbose, PSWarning, Result, Verbose, WarningAction.

Just to clarify there is no change in the runbook script it was running for 2 years untouched.

I have checked the server for changes and found that over the weekend these KB were updated on the server. I have removed a KB each and restarted the server and checked still the same error.

These are the KB updates.

- KB4343888
- KB4344171
- KB4457143
- KB4462941
- KB4462949

Steps I followed:
Removed the latest updates on the servers

Server Details:

- Windows 2012 R2
- SMA UiPath Control Center
- Powershell 4.0
- .Net 4.5

Please help fix this issue.

Regards

Comment: Please post the full problematic command and the lines around it (ie. line 10 through 14 or something like that)

Comment: Please show us the full line 12 that begins with `Get-AutomationVariable “TestExecutor_Computers”`. Perhaps it has something to do with the curly quotes and you should replace them with straight ones. like `Get-AutomationVariable -Name "TestExecutor_Computers"`